# selenium find element using Xpath

Tags: selenium

Any one help me how to find this element in selenium using java? when i Copy Xpath then it thrown Exception

[image: element screenshot]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/approot/div/headerselector/header/div[2]/div[2]/img")).click();
```

Comment: Instend of posting photo,can you please upload the HTML Code?

Comment: Could you add the exception and html snippet

Comment: @MoazzamHussain Instead of the image update the question with the text based relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your desired xpath: `"//i[contains(@_ng-content-c6 class,'fa fa-plus')]"`

Get firtst button with this xpath:

```
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@_ng-content-c6 class,'fa fa-plus')]"));
    button.click();
```

Get any button with this xpath:

```
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[contains(@_ng-content-c6 class,'fa fa-plus')]"));
    buttons.get(0).click();
    // buttons.get(1).click();
    // ...
```

More about relative xpath: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Thnks I will try it.